# Get list of all holidays from google calendar api with Python

Tags: python, google-api, calendar

I've checkmarked all the countries to be added to my google calendar. now, using the google api, I am trying to retrieve all the holidays, day by day.

so far i have:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/holiday']
creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin = '2021-01-01T00:00:00Z',
                              timeMax='2022-01-02T00:00:00Z').execute()
```

which only returns

```
{'kind': 'calendar#events',
 'etag': '"p32kbjd5mnaof20g"',
 'summary': 'ncl.rm.business.analysis@gmail.com',
 'updated': '2021-06-24T14:15:13.401Z',
 'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
 'accessRole': 'owner',
 'defaultReminders': [{'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 30}],
 'nextSyncToken': 'CKi5tLa6sPECEKi5tLa6sPECGAUguITQtQE=',
 'items': []}
```

no matter what i change in my events/scope variable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you use `primary` as your `calendarId` you are retreiving events from the primary calendar of the logged in user (you), not the holiday calendar.

Comment: Thanks ! do you know how I can retrieve all the holidays like i originally intended ?

Comment: What happens if you use `en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com` as your `calendarId`?

Comment: It gives me all the holidays for the USA... will I have to iterate over a list of 100+ countries ?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so, if that's what you want. Beware of API rate limits if you attempt this. Other sources of national holidays are probably available.